# MySQL query to get total item number from table 2 to owner in table 1?

Tags: php, mysql

I got 2 tables: Owners and Storage as below:

**Table: owners**

```
id  |   owner    |  box
----------------------------
1   |   Nick     |  []
2   |   Jack     |  []
3   |   Jane     |  []
```

**Table: Storage**

```
id  |  fruit  | owner_id
---------------------------
1   |  Apple  |   1
2   |  Apple  |   3
3   |  Banana |   2
4   |  Banana |   1
5   |  Banana |   1
6   |  orange |   1
7   |  Apple  |   3
8   |  Orange |   2
9   |  Apple  |   2
```

**Question: Is there a query to get how many fruit in each owner's box in result?**
Like:

```
Nick:[Apple:1,Banan:2,Orange:1]
Jack:[Apple:1,Banan:1,Orange:1]
Jane:[Apple:2,Banan:0,Orange:0]
```

I tried to join 2 tables but it return me hundreds of records that duplicated. Much appreciated if anyone could guide me out.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT owners.id, 
       JSON_OBJECTAGG(fruits.fruit, COALESCE(boxes.cnt, 0)) boxes
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT fruit
      FROM Storage) fruits
CROSS JOIN owners
LEFT JOIN (SELECT owners.id, Storage.fruit, COUNT(*) cnt
           FROM owners
           JOIN Storage ON owners.id = Storage.owner_id
           GROUP BY owners.id, Storage.fruit) boxes ON owners.id = boxes.id
                                                   AND fruits.fruit = boxes.fruit
GROUP BY owners.id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=87f92ead7685f02922f609414da98685)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT owner, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('(', fruit,',',c,')') SEPARATOR ';') as counts
FROM 
    (SELECT owner, owner_id, fruit, COUNT(*) as c FROM `storage` 
     JOIN owners ON owners.id = storage.owner_id
     GROUP BY fruit, owner_id) as t 
GROUP BY owner_id
```

The key here is the request in the parenthesis

```
SELECT owner_id, fruit, COUNT(*) as c FROM `storage` GROUP BY fruit, owner_id
```

which gives something like

```
owner_id | fruit  | c
---------------------
1        | apple  | 1
1        | banana | 2
1        | orange | 1
```

and you just do group concat with fruit and c columns